# ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor Rendering Partials from One Controllers View to Another Controllers View

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-partialview

What is the best way to redirect to another partial view from a partial view without refreshing the main page. So 1 partial view changing into another partial view after a button click. Can you do this with jQuery , or is there a better way to perform this?
Also you need to pass an id with it

Answer (score 3):

AJAX seems like a good solution in this case. So you could place a button somewhere on the page:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "link text",
    "someAction",
    "someController",
    new { id = "put here some id you want to send to server" },
    new { id = "myLink" }
)

<div id="partial2Div"></div>
```

and then unobtrusively AJAXify this link in a separate javascript file:

```
$(function() {
    $('#myLink').click(function() {
        $('#partial2Div').load(this.href);
        return false;
    });
});
```

The controller action will simply return the corresponding partial view:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(string id)
{
    var model = ...
    return PartialView(model);
}
```

Comment: if i delete the return false, he shows the new partial view giving a whole new page. If i use return false (like in your example) nothing happens

Comment: @Thomas, you can inspect the AJAX request in FireBug. You will see whether the controller action is hit and what it returns.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax.ActionLink will do this for you out of the box without having to write additional javascript code.

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Link Text","Action","Controller",new {id= myId},new AjaxOptions{InsertionMode=InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod="get", UpdateTargetId="target-location-id"})
```

Comment: when I click the actionlink, a new page renders. The partial view must change page, not the parent page.

Comment: Have you included the required javascript files: jquery,
MicrosoftAjax.js and MicrosoftMvcAjax.js?

Comment: yes, I placed it on my parent page, but it still gives me a new page (even the method is of type PartialViewResult instead of ActionResult)

Comment: it should be simple i guess, having a parent page and a partial view in it and the partial view renders a new view inside it when you click a actionlink or button.

Comment: Does a div or similar with the id specified by "updatetargetid" exist?

If you click on the link in firefox, is there a javascript error in the error console (tools->error console)

Comment: <a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="post" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#partial2Div" href="/Home/Create">Create Company</a>. Under this codepart there is a div with id partial2Div . You expect that it will render in the div, but opens a new page

Comment: Are you sure you want to use POST? I'd suggest you probably want to change the protocol to get. You probably have an action method for create that looks like

public ActionResult Create() { return PartialView("_Create"); } 

[HttpPost]

[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]

public ActionResult Create(Company company) { etc etc }

When you use POST it's going to call the later method, instead of the former. It's probably encountering an error because you haven't passed a company and/or antiforgerytoken, or whatever parameters the create POST action method want.

Comment: i found this on msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381533.aspx, but this doesn't work neither. The solution of that example should replace the status in the span section, right? but it opens a new page

Comment: What javascript errors are there in the firefox error console?

Comment: no errors seen in the error console, if u build the solution on msdn, does it render the info on the same page or a new page? mine gives a new page (although it should render information on the same page, i suppose)